# why changing location using js create new instances of window, document?

Tags: javascript, window.location

I don't really get how this works.
Doing something like

```
window.addEventlistener("whatever", ()=>{...})
```

and then doing

```
window.location = somewhere
```

or

```
window.document.location = somewhere
```

leads to window no longer having anything I put on it at the first place. So I guess, it's creating another window instance.

I expected the window to keep listeners I put on it (at least if I'm using window.document.location).

What did I take wrong?